# Define a constructor parameter for a synthetic class in a Scala Compiler Plugin?

Tags: scala, parameters, constructor, synthetic

I'm trying to generate a class in a Scala compiler Plugin. I have a trait Test, and need a class TestWrapper, approximately like this:

```
class TestWrapper(wrapped: Test) extends Test { ... }
```

I define the constructor parameter like this:

```
val pName = newTermName("wrapped")
val paramSym = myNewClass.newValueParameter(owner.pos.focus, pName)
paramSym.setInfo(wrapped.tpe).setFlag(SYNTHETIC)
val param = ValDef(paramSym)
```

and later the ClassDef:

```
ClassDef(myNewClass, NoMods, List(List(param)), List(Nil),
        members, owner.pos)
```

which receives the parameter. Currently, what I get is:

```
// Scala source: Test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of generatewrappers]]
package test {
  <synthetic> class TestWrapper extends Object with test.Test {
    <synthetic> val wrapped: test.Test = _;
    def this(wrapped: test.Test): test.TestWrapper = {
      TestWrapper.super.this();
      ()
    };
    <synthetic> def m3: Int = TestWrapper.this.wrapped.m3;
  };
```

The compiler seems to be automatically generating a field with the same name as the parameter. What I don't see is the assignment from the parameter to the field, but I had assumed it was "implicit". I can than instantiate this TestWrapper with a concrete instance of Test, but calling m3 causes an Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: wrapped
    at test.TestWrapper.m3(Test.scala:1)
    ...
```

"wrapped" should in fact be 3 different things:

```
1) A constructor parameter
2) An class instance field
3) A getter for the class instance field
```

The output of the compiler shows after all that there *is* a field:

```
<synthetic> val wrapped: test.Test = _;
```

and that it is defined, because of the "= _", as opposed to undefined, when there is no "= ..."

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I needed to add the following line:

```
myNewClass.info.decls.enter(paramSym)
```

Duh!